# Hierarchy in LogiXML through Excel file

Tags: .net, xml, excel

my issue is the following.  I am trying to build a hierarchical view of the data I have which is compromised of two levels.  The 1st (highest) level would be called "Group" and the 2nd (lowest) level "Facility".  What I'm trying to do is having the ability of creating some metrics through logixml (such as Volume, etc) with row level data found in the excel file. The problem I'm encountering is that I'm not able to give that hierarchical structure view to the data, meaning, I do not know of a way to "tell" LogiXML to group the data in the manner I want it to.  Excel does what I want with a pivot table, but this is not an acceptable presentation manner:

```
Group1                                          1464    1.033592841
 Facility1------------------------------         788    1.224048166
 Facility2------------------------------         517    0.56564287
 Facility3---------------------------             26    1.015306122
 Facility4-------------------------------         55    0.754109589

Group2                                              1077    0.48911388
 Facility1------------------------------------      1077    0.48911388
```

Any help on how or where to edit the excel file so that I can build this hierarchy in LogiXML will be appreciated.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to "explode" your groups such that the hierarchies are represented at each row-level.   That way the GroupFilter in Logi can applied at the column level.

Something like this..

Group1 | Facility1 | 788 | 1.22

Group1 | Facility2 | 517 | 0.56

Group1 | Facility3 | 26  | 1.01

Group2 | Facility1 | 1077| 0.48

...

Where each row has the top-level group as a column-value.   That way you could apply your grouping on that column value effectively.

If the data is already pivoted inside Excel, you can also try using the  datalayer element in Logi to automatically explode out the data for easier formatting inside your report definition.

For more detail on using the UnCrosstab filter, you might view this article:
http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1253